# Accessing Elements on electron webview using spectron

Tags: webdriver, electron, webdriver-io

I am trying to automate a electron app which loads its content on to an webview. I am using spectron and webdriverio for it.

here is the code i am using.

```
it('should assess webview', function() {
    var self = this;
    return this.app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
        .windowHandles().then(function(session) {
            self.app.client.switchTab(session.value[1])
            .click("#my-id")
            .then(console.log.bind(console))
            .catch(console.log.bind(console));
        });
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. i am not sure where i am going wrong. But i used

```
it('should assess webview', function() {
    var self = this;
    return this.app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
        .windowHandles().then(function(session) {
            self.app.client.switchTab(session.value[1])
            .getSource()
            .then(console.log.bind(console))
            .catch(console.log.bind(console));
        });
});
```

the above code to ensure whether the webview window handle is correct. And it is. Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the code, using spectron and running webview inside simulating this behaviour, your code works fine. Re-written the codes. Hope this helps.

```
it('should assess webview', function() {
    var self = this;
    return this.app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
        .windowHandles().then(function(session) {
            // Need to return the promise back, if promise is
            // it would wait for the state or else app will exit.
            return self.app.client.switchTab(session.value[1])
            .click("#my-id") // check whether selector is present in DOM
            .then(console.log.bind(console))
            .catch(console.log.bind(console));
        });
});
```

or

```
it('should assess webview', function() {
    var self = this;
    return this.app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
        .windowHandles()
        .then(function(session) {
            // switchTab & window will both focus
            // window or tab which is active
            return this.window(session.value[1])
        })
        .click("#my-id") // check whether selector is present in DOM
        .then(console.log.bind(console))
        .catch(console.log.bind(console));;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kamesh i will check it.